# my onChildAdded() works when use the Firebase push() but not the update

Tags: java, android, firebase

It seems that my `onChildAdded()` method isn't working whenever I use the `updateChildren()` method. It works with the `push().setValue()` approach.
Both methods sends data to Firebase just fine. 
Any ideas?

thanks!

Here is the `push()` method (that works)

```
private void saveToFirebase() {

    String username = getIntent().getStringExtra("Username");

    //takes string user input and creates a child of Gaben(parent)
    Firebase usersRef = myFirebaseRef.child(username);

    //sub child
    Firebase location = usersRef.child("details");

    Map mLocations = new HashMap();
    mLocations.put("timestamp", mLastUpdateTime);
    Map mCoordinate = new HashMap();

    myFirebaseRef.push().setValue(mLocations);
}

private void drawLocations() {
    // Get only latest logged locations - since 'START' button clicked
    Query queryRef = myFirebaseRef.orderByChild("timestamp").startAt(startLoggingTime);
    // Add listener for a child added at the data at this location
    queryRef.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        LatLngBounds bounds;
        LatLngBounds.Builder builder = new LatLngBounds.Builder();

        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            Map data = (Map) dataSnapshot.getValue();
            String timestamp = (String) data.get("timestamp");
            // Get recorded latitude and longitude
            Map mCoordinate = (HashMap) data.get("location");

            double latitude = (double) (mCoordinate.get("latitude"));
            double longitude = (double) (mCoordinate.get("longitude"));

            // Create LatLng for each locations
            LatLng mLatlng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);

            // Make sure the map boundary contains the location
            builder.include(mLatlng);
            bounds = builder.build();

            //get username input from login activity
            String username = getIntent().getStringExtra("Username");

            MarkerOptions mMarkerOption = new MarkerOptions()
                    // Add a marker for each logged location
                    .position(mLatlng)
                    .title(username)
                    .snippet(timestamp)
                    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_AZURE));

            Marker nMarker = mMap.addMarker(mMarkerOption);
            nMarker.showInfoWindow();

            // Zoom map to the boundary that contains every logged location
            mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds, MAP_ZOOM_LEVEL));
        }
    });
}
```

here is the `update()` method that doesn't work

```
private void saveToFirebase() {
    String username = getIntent().getStringExtra("Username");

    //takes string user input and creates a child of Gaben(parent)
    Firebase usersRef = myFirebaseRef.child(username);

    //sub child
    Firebase location = usersRef.child("details");

    Map mLocations = new HashMap();
    mLocations.put("timestamp", mLastUpdateTime);
    Map  mCoordinate = new HashMap();

    mCoordinate.put("latitude", mCurrentLocation.getLatitude());
    mCoordinate.put("longitude", mCurrentLocation.getLongitude());

    //updates location in firebase
    location.updateChildren(mLocations);
    location.updateChildren(mCoordinate);
}
```

basically the only difference is that push method creates unique id's every time, the other simply updates it.

the only difference is these lines

```
    location.updateChildren(mCoordinate);
```

and this

```
    myFirebaseRef.push().setValue(mLocations);
```

Answer (score 1):

Updating an existing location is not the same as adding a new location.

From the [Firebase documentation on event types](https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/guide/retrieving-data.html#section-types):

> The **onChildAdded** event ... is triggered once for each existing child and then again every time a new child is **added** to the specified path.

And:

> The **onChildChanged** event is triggered any time a child node is **modified**.

Since you're adding new locations and modifying existing ones, you'll have to implement both `onChildAdded()` and `onChildChanged()`.

Comment: Yeah I figured it had something to do with that. I solved the problem. thanks for your input :)